# Where can I find the assets api used on the coinbase website?

Tags: coinbase-api

I want to build chart for currencies like charts on the coinbase website. When I inspected the request for this api, the api is 
https://www.coinbase.com/api/v2/assets/BTC-USD/historic?resolution=day

it also can be accessed http://api.coinbase.com/v2/assets/BTC-USD/historic?resolution=day

But I didn't see any documents about this api from developers resources.
Can someone tell me about that?

Thank you,